# Update readonly field in in DRF serializer from Viewset data

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer in DRF as follows:

```
class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    full_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    email_id = serializers.EmailField()
    jira_ticket = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['full_name', 'email_id', 'jira_ticket']



class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def create(self, request):
        serializer = UserRegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user_obj= UserWorkFlow(request_data=request.data,                                                        
                                   serializer=serializer)
            response = user_obj.response()
            return response
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

As is evident, this is a serializer to create a new user on the system.It needs the **full_name** and the **email_id** of the user in the request payload to create the new user.As part of the user creation, a **jira_ticket** is created separately.

However, the Jira ticket data is available only in the **View** and not the **Serializer**.How do I capture this data from the view and update my serializer, so the that response has the **jira_ticket** information ?

Comment: Can you add your view code?

Comment: Did you checked https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/ `perform_create()` in `Save and deletion hooks:`

Comment: @Amistad You will get `jira_ticket` from `UserWorkFlow` class and you want to save it to user instance ...right?

Comment: @JPG..my user model has no field for jira_ticket..and hence I don't want to save it to the user model..I just want to display it in the serialised output..I tried appending it to the serialised.data dict but looks like that is immutable..